# iPhone application development

Tags: iphone, development-environment

I’m building my portfolio as a freelance graphic designer, and I develop designs for mobile apps. I’ve got android app development down, but I’m not sure if my knowledge of iPhone application development extends to the newest iO7 operating system. I’ve noticed that whenever a new operating system is available for iPhones, some of the apps for the previous system don’t work anymore. Does anyone know how I can keep up with the nuances of the newest iPhone operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're going through as I was myself in a position like yours.

So, what you need to understand is that the iOS development standards never completely change. The language i.e. Objective-C will always be the same. Now, there are of course improvements.

The most important keyword for you to know is **deprecation**. If a `method` or a `class` is deprecated, it means that it works for older versions of iOS but not for the latest one. Almost 99% of the time, that `method` or `class` is replaced by a newer, better one and it is clearly mentioned in the documentation.

So, I'd recommend that you start out by learning iOS 7 development only. Believe it or not, the major change in iOS 7 is mainly its looks and the core development concepts still remain in place.

Optimizing your app for previous operating systems is mostly a no-brainer. There are several tutorials online and its nothing a through Google search can't solve.

As someone who also came from an Android background, I can understand the urge to sometimes find certain similarities between the development process. There are nothing but misconceptions and don't think of such thing while making your app otherwise you might run into some very big problems.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Apple developer, there are many different resources at you finger tips such as the new "Tech Talks" that explain new things that are coming into play for IOS Development. However, if you are not a developer there are still some ways to keep up with it such as watching the annual keynotes and checking their website regularly. One way that is possibly the most effective is to use it. Also it is always good to explore Xcode and things like the object library. When you preform the update on your iPhone, read the details of what is new in this update. Hope this helped